# LinkedHashMap and NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linkedhashmap

I have been working on building a name generator based off of Markov Chains. So far, the code can find the probability of the next letter and place it nicely in the `LinkedHashMap` (Which I will refer to as LHM past this point) named `states` by using the `generateProbabilities()` function. The LHM stores the data so that the first key is the state, and the second is the transition letter.

However, this is where things start to get interesting. I have three output statements, one in the `generate()` function, and two in the `WeightedRandom` init. Here is my output:

EDITED SECTION:

```
Called from generate(): [0.13333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.06666666666666667, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.06666666666666667]
Called from WeightedRandom (Size): 10
Called from WeightedRandom (Values): [0.13333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.06666666666666667, 0.13333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.06666666666666667]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WeightedRandom.<init>(WeightedRandom.java:14)
    at MarkovChain.generate(MarkovChain.java:102)
    at Temp.main(Temp.java:7)
```

The weird part is that the NPE on line 14 is the second println statement in `WeightedRandom`, and it was thrown after it printed out the data. The third println prints without an error. So, it isn't like I forgot to initialize it, or didn't have the right key to get the NPE. The code is below:

MarkovChain.java

```
public class MarkovChain {
public String filePath;
public LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Double>> states = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String,Double>>();

public MarkovChain(String filePath){
    this.filePath = filePath;
}
public void generateProbabilities(String delimiter){
  //Creates a hashmap of probabilities for each letter.
}

public String generate(int iterations){
    Random rand = new Random();
    LinkedHashMap<String,Double> currProbabilities = states.get("a"); // Placeholder for random start state;
    String output = "";
    WeightedRandom weightRand;

    System.out.println("Called from generate(): " + currProbabilities.values());
    for(int i = 0; i<iterations; i++){
        weightRand = new WeightedRandom(currProbabilities);
        String newState = weightRand.compute();
        output+=newState;
        currProbabilities = states.get(newState);
    }

    return output;
}
}
```

WeightedRandom.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class WeightedRandom {
LinkedHashMap<String,Double> items;
Random rand = new Random();

public WeightedRandom(LinkedHashMap<String,Double> items){ //Currently Single-Purpose.
    this.items = items;
    System.out.println("Called from WeightedRandom (Size): " + items.size());
    System.out.println("Called from WeightedRandom (Values): " + items.values());

}

public String compute(){
    items.values();
    /*
    Set s = items.entrySet();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();
    double randNum = rand.nextDouble();
    double runningTotal = 0;
    String output = null;
    while(i.hasNext() && output == null){
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        if(randNum < runningTotal + (double)entry.getValue() && randNum > runningTotal){
            output = (String)entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return output;
    */
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the NPE and its stack trace.

Comment: Do you always have a value for "a" in the beginning, where `states.get("a")` is called?

Comment: @jingx I am not sure what you mean by having a value for `states.get("a")`, but the stack trace is in the question above now.

Comment: You are calling `states.get("a")` when initializing `currProbabilities`. If there isn't anything by the key `"a"` in `states`, that's going to return `null`.

Comment: So, I updated the question above to make it clearer. It isn't the fact that states.get("a") is null. It gives me the values as well as an error. I put the output above as well to show you what I mean

Comment: Never mind. I forgot that I had an iterator around the WeightedRandom, and the `compute` function was not actually working, and returning the `null` value that gave me the weird results. Thank you for your time!